# Unable to Establish S2S Connection Between Two Salesforce Orgs

Tags: integration

I have two salesforce orgs and I want to establish S2S connection. However I have created a connection instance but I am unable to receive mail which salesforce sends for accepting or declining the connection request. While creating the connection in sender org, I have added the contact and account of the sender account, but the same contact also exists in receiver org. But I am unable to receive connection request mail on my email Id from salesforce. Can anyone please suggest the entire process to establish S2S to share account and contact records.

Comment: The contact being in both orgs is irrelevant. Until receiver org enables S2S and accepts your invitation, you won't receive an email from Salesforce confirming the S2S connection has been made. Both Orgs need to have S2S enabled. One Org sends invitation & other accepts. It's all in the documentation if you follow it closely.

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev. Can you please provide the link of that documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you start in Salesforce Help at the links below located under "Setup and Maintain Sales Tools" then work through configuring your Salesforce to Salesforce integration from there:

- [Salesforce to Salesforce Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=business_network_intro.htm&type=0)
- [Enable Salesforce to Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=business_network_enabling.htm&type=0)